# How to clear/reset the WPF Crystal Report Viewer

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, crystal-reports

Let me first of all start by saying that I'm by no means a WPF expert, so if I've missed something then my apologies.

I'm working on an application written in C#, with WPF using the MVVM pattern.  What I'm working on is a generic report viewer view.  The design of the form is fairly simple, a combobox control and a tab control with 2 tabs.  The first tab has a custom parameters control and the second has a WPF Crystal Reports (CR) Viewer.

The function of the form is also fairly simple, when you change the combobox selection it looks up the appropriate CR report (using the desktop engine, CR for VS2010) and queries the design for parameters which are then displayed in tab 1.  The user fills in the parameters as required and presses the "go" button which passes the parameter values back to the report, executes and puts it into the viewer control on tab 2, which is brought to focus.

That all works great, you can change the combo, fill in the parameters and view reports repeatedly without any drama.  The problem has come up as more of a "usability" issue.

If you already have a report selected and viewed in the CR viewer, when you select a new report you have the parameters for the second report in the parameters tab, but the preview for the first report still in the viewer which, depending on the user, can be confusing.

When the user selects a new report, the parameters are focused but I want to "clear" the CR viewer and I can't work out how to make this happen.  I set the report in an event in the View code behind that is called from the method in the ViewModel by the "go" button press.

```
this.crystalReportsViewer.ViewerCore.ReportSource = this.ViewModel.Report;
```

But nothing I've tried lets me clear the report viewer.

```
this.crystalReportsViewer.ViewerCore.ReportSource = null;

this.crystalReportsViewer.Content = null;

this.crystalReportsViewer.ViewerCore.Content = null;

this.crystalReportsViewer.ViewerCore.ReportSource = new ReportDocument();

this.crystalReportsViewer = new CrystalReportsViewer();
this.crystalReportsViewer.Owner = Window.GetWindow(this);
```

I can't close and reopen the view between report generation attempts, and making the control visible or hidden as required is such a horrible kludge.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!